# Replace digits and then characters pattern with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file like below:

```
some
arbitrary number of
leading
lines
a prefix followed by wmd v0.0.0-20220406135915-ce5e3ee6c6bf
some
trailing
lines
```

This is only an example of what the file could look like. The unvarying parts are that, for the line I am interested in:

- There is always `wmd v0.0.0-`, followed by
- 14 digits, followed by
- a hyphen, followed by
- 12 alphanumeric characters

How can I write a `sed` command that will allow me to replace the `20220406135915-ce5e3ee6c6bf` portion with the value in a shell variable `new_text`?

In other words, if `new_text` had the value `99999999999999-aaaaaaaaaaaa`, I want to find the `<whatever goes here>` part of the `sed` command that would produce the following output:

```
$ sed -e "s/wmd v0.0.0-<whatever goes here>/wmd v0.0.0-$new_text/" my-file.txt
some
arbitrary number of
leading
lines
a prefix followed by wmd v0.0.0-99999999999999-aaaaaaaaaaaa
some
trailing
lines
```

Comment: Would using `.*` for `<whatever goes here>` be too generic? Your example input doesn't reveal whether it could possibly match somewhere else.

Comment: @Kusalananda, `.*` might not be too generic, but I prefer to be less generic just in case. Plus, I wanted to understand how to specify quantifiers on character classes with `sed`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `\{..\}` quantifiers to specify how many times a character class should match.

```
sed -e "s/wmd v0\.0\.0-[0-9]\{14\}-[0-9a-f]\{12\}/wmd v0.0.0-$new_text/"
#               ~  ~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Also note that a dot has a special meaning in regular expressions. Backslash it to match literally.

Also note that if `$new_text` contained a slash or some other characters special to sed, the command can break.

Comment: For lovers of mnemonics, `[[:xdigit:]]` will match a hexadecimal digit, lower or upper case.

Comment: and for those who don't love backslashes, most seds support `sed -E` for extended regexes, which would allow using `{14}` and `{12}` without the backslashes

Comment: Bash parameter expansion can launder `$new_text` to make it suitable as a replacement string, e.g. with `replacement=${new_text//'\\/\\\\}; replacement=${replacement//&/\\&}; replacement=${replacement//\//\\/}`.  For plain POSIX shell, we need a command substitution: `replacement=$(echo $new_text|sed 's,[\\/&],\\&,g')`

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```bsh
~$ raku -pe 's/ "wmd v0.0.0-" <( \d**14 \- \w**12 )> /99999999999999-aaaaaaaaaaaa/'  my-file.txt

#OR

~$ raku -pe 's[ "wmd v0.0.0-" <( \d**14 \- \w**12 )> ] = "99999999999999-aaaaaaaaaaaa";'  my-file.txt
```

Sample Input:

```
some
arbitrary number of
leading
lines
a prefix followed by wmd v0.0.0-20220406135915-ce5e3ee6c6bf
some
trailing
lines
```

Sample Output:

```
some
arbitrary number of
leading
lines
a prefix followed by wmd v0.0.0-99999999999999-aaaaaaaaaaaa
some
trailing
lines
```

The above regex uses 4 regex atoms to identify the match, `"wmd v0.0.0-"`, `\d**14`, `\-`, and `\w**12`. Of course, if you have a problem with quotes, `"wmd v0.0.0-"` can be written `wmd \s v0 \. 0 \. 0 \-` (i.e. all non-`alnum` characters are backslash-escaped).

Capture markers `<( … )>` are used to drop everything outside of the `\d**14 \- \w**12`, which gets replaced in the right half of the `s///` operator.

Note, in the above code `\w` is shorthand for `<alnum>`, which includes `_` underscore. If you don't want to accept `_` underscore (indeed, potentially 12 consecutive `_` underscore characters), use something like `<[0..9a..z]>**12` instead.

Finally, you can simplify your substitutions by abstracting the replacement into a variable, like so:

```bsh
~$ raku -pe 'my $new = "99999999999999-aaaaaaaaaaaa"; \
             s/ "wmd v0.0.0-" <( \d**14 \- <[0..9a..z]>**12 )> /$new/;'  my-file.txt
```

https:raku.org